# Counting SQLite rows

Tags: android

How to count the number of rows in an `SQLite` database table? I have a table called `my_table` and it has columns `name` `info` and `number`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You may use rawQuery `count(*)` which returns number of rows in a table.

```
   cursor=db.rawQuery("Select count(*) from my_table;", null);
```

Comment: jsut looked it up `count(*)` returns all records. `count(<column>)` was the one i was looking for. Thanks

Comment: If you want only column specific you may need to pass column name as parameter. Refer this link http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_func_count.asp

Answer (score 4):

Use `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM " + DB_TABLE_PLACES` query to get number of rows present in the table
**Example**

```
private static final String DB_TABLE_PLACES = "my_table";
private SQLiteDatabase mDatabase;

private long fetchPlacesCount() {
    String sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM " + DB_TABLE_PLACES;
    SQLiteStatement statement = mDatabase.compileStatement(sql);
    long count = statement.simpleQueryForLong();
    return count;
}
```

Comment: shouldn't i specify `count(<columnname>)`?