# C++ how to execute to return number of row with this sqlite statement

Tags: c++, sqlite

I would like to execute select count(*) from abe_account; and get the return result assign to int counter;

but how do i execute if i already execute the sql statement below.

I not sure where to insert to add in another sql command and obtain the result and recast it into int counter;

```
   sqlite3 *db;
   sqlite3_stmt * stmt;
   std::vector< std::vector < std:: string > > result;

   for( int i = 0; i < 4; i++ )
        result.push_back(std::vector< std::string >());

   if (sqlite3_open("abeserver.db", &db) == SQLITE_OK)
   {
       sqlite3_prepare( db, "SELECT * from abe_account;", -1, &stmt, NULL );//preparing the statement
       sqlite3_step( stmt );//executing the statement

       while( sqlite3_column_text( stmt, 0 ) )
       {
           for( int i = 0; i < 4; i++ )
               result[i].push_back( std::string( (char *)sqlite3_column_text( stmt, i ) ) );

           sqlite3_step( stmt );
       }
   }
```

Comment: Apart from missing the `GROUP BY` clause you have some logic bugs which may cause an infinite loop or access violations. Perhaps refer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9467381/sqlite-row-count)

Comment: perhaps this example will help.  There's some abstraction in the library, but it uses sqlite + c to do a select count(*) from a table.  http://www.midnightbsd.org/cgi-bin/cvsweb.cgi/src/lib/libmport/pkgmeta.c?rev=1.9;content-type=text%2Fplain