# Put Sql Data to a Number Array

Tags: java, android, sql, arrays, eclipse

I have a problem. How can I put data from a SQL database to a Number array. I would like to put them in a Graph

I got a `NullPointerException` for these command

```
Number[] series2Numbers={s1nInt[1]};
```

Here is my full code

```
openDB();
Cursor c = myDb.getSpalte();        

while (c.moveToPrevious())
{        
    s1nInt[i] = c.getInt(1);
    i++;
    c.moveToPrevious();

}
c.close();
closeDB();    

Number[] series2Numbers={s1nInt[1]};
```

And here is my exception:

```
Graph.onStart() line: 85    
Graph(Fragment).performStart() line: 1801   
FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(Fragment, int, int, int, boolean) line: 937 
 FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(int, int, int, boolean) line: 1106 
 BackStackRecord.run() line: 690    
 FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions() line: 1571    
FragmentManagerImpl$1.run() line: 447   
Handler.handleCallback(Message) line: 733   
Handler.dispatchMessage(Message) line: 95
```

My getSpalte()

```
public Cursor getSpalte(){
    String where= null;
    String Order = "_id DESC";
    Cursor c =  db.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, KEY_KALOA, 
            where, null, null, null, Order, null);
  if (c != null) {
  c.moveToFirst();
}
  return c;
}
```

i need the array for this:

```
 XYSeries series1 = new SimpleXYSeries(
                     Arrays.asList(series1Numbers),          // SimpleXYSeries takes a List so turn our array into a List
                     SimpleXYSeries.ArrayFormat.Y_VALS_ONLY, // Y_VALS_ONLY means use the element index as the x value
                     "Series1");                             // Set the display title of the series
```

Comment: Show us your database query (in `getSpalte()`). I guess myDb is of your own type, since it has a method named "getSpalte()". And please include the structure  of the queied table(s) too.

Comment: At first glance, it seems that the size of the `s1nInt` array is less than 2.

Comment: @Michael: At second glance you'll recognize that this would produce a `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` instead of the NPE. It looks like the result has only 1 column, however.

Comment: @fabian You are correct.. Sorry..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`s1nInt` is `null` in the line

```
Number[] series2Numbers={s1nInt[1]};
```

Maybe you never initialize `s1nInt` or set it to `null` somewhere. This is the only part of the line that could produce a `NullPointerException`.

Also that implies that `c.moveToPrevious()` failed.

#### From api doc of [`Cursor.moveToPrevious()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html#moveToPrevious%28%29):

> This method will return false if the cursor is already before the first entry in the result set.

Maybe you have to change `moveToPrevious()` to `moveToNext()` too. (The cursor is at the position before the first entry directly after the query).

Also you move the cursor **twice** in each loop iteration. That way you'll only get **either** the odd **or** the even rows.

---

#### Update

After your latest edits to the question it seems that you need a `List<? extends Number>` and not an array. Since all elements of the list will be `Integer`s, you should use `ArrayList<Integer>`. That way you reduce the danger of `null` elements and the list. Your code could look like this:

```
public Cursor getSpalte(){
    String where= null;
    String Order = "_id DESC";
    Cursor c =  db.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, KEY_KALOA, // hope KEY_KALOA is guarantied to be correct here
            where, null, null, null, Order, null);
    return c;
}
```

```
openDB();
Cursor c = myDb.getSpalte();
List<Integer> valueList = new ArrayList<Integer>(c.getCount());

while (c.moveToNext()) {        
    valueList.add(c.getInt(0)); // assuming the first column is of type INT
}
c.close();
closeDB();

XYSeries series1 = new SimpleXYSeries(
                 valueList,
                 SimpleXYSeries.ArrayFormat.Y_VALS_ONLY,
                 "Series1");
```

There are several alternatives to using a `ArrayList` directly, depending on what you need:

- If you fear the `List` could be modified, you can create a list that doesn't support modification using `Collections.unmodifiableList(List)`.
- If you indeed need only 1 element in the list, you can use `Cursor.moveToPosition(int)` and `Collections.singletonList(Integer)`

Comment: the i got these Exception `06-28 12:00:26.956: E/CursorWindow(5510): Failed to read row 1, column 1 from a CursorWindow which has 3 rows, 1 columns.
`

Comment: @user3779128: The index is zero-based, which means column 1 is at index 0 not at index 1. (see [Cursor.getInt(int) API doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html#getInt%28int%29))

Comment: hmm and how could I change that he do this?

Comment: @user3779128: I'm not sure if i understood that comment correctly (Who is "he"?), but if you want to fix that error should change `c.getInt(1)` to `c.getInt(0)`.

Comment: hmm.but I doesnt helped

Comment: @user3779128: Did you get a different exception this time? Since the column index should now be valid and the row index seems to be valid the exception should be different.

Comment: because s1nInt[1]=null...hmm

Comment: I added some more Info...Can I solve the problem on another way?

Comment: Could you tell me how can I see how data are in there?:)

Comment: @user3779128: [Cursor.getCount()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html#getCount%28%29) for a `Cursor` (that's why I use it as initial capacity of the `ArrayList`) or if you only want to retrieve the number of rows from the database you can use `COUNT(*)` (see [this answer to the question "How to count the number of rows in an SqLite database table?"](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9467428/2991525))